# 6-dim semisimple Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\frak g$  be a semisimple Lie algebra with $dim\ \mathfrak g=  6$. How to prove that $\mathfrak g\cong \mathfrak {sl}(2,\mathbb C)\oplus \mathfrak {sl}(2,\mathbb C)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Cartan decomposition we know that 
$$
6=\dim L=\dim H+ |\Phi|
$$
where $H$ is a Cartan subalgebra of $L$ and $\Phi$ the root system of $L$.
The number $\ell=\dim H$ is the *rank* of $L$. For $\ell=1$ we know that $L\simeq \frak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ already, so we may assume that $\ell\ge 2$. For $\ell \ge 3$ we would have $|\Phi|\le 3$. In that case it is easy to see using the axioms of a root system that only $\Phi=\{\alpha,-\alpha\}$ is possible. But this would imply $\dim H=1$, a contradiction. Hence we are left with the possibility $\ell=2$. All root systems can be easily classifed
in this case, with the reuslt that $L$ is one of the following possibilities: $A_1\oplus A_1,B_2,C_2,D_2,G_2$. However, only $A_1\oplus A_1$ has dimension $6$. So we are done.

Comment: Why $|\Phi|=2$ implies that $dim\ H=1$? Thanks

Comment: From the roots $\{-\alpha,\alpha\}$ one can form the Cartan numbers, which explicitly give the Lie brackets. Not surprisingly, it turns out that we get $[x,y]=h, [x,h]=-2x,[y,h]=2y$, which is $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$, so that $\dim H=1$.